# How to get Material-UI DropDownMenu to return the selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**This is my first time posting on StackOverFlow - bear with me**

I'm building a React app and collecting info from my users that requires me to use a DropDownMenu with Material-UI . I would like to the dropdown menu to record a string value for the option that the user selects, and set it to state. The way the code is written, it only pushes an integer 'value' to state, which does not correlate in anyway to the string value that the user selects. I have been playing with writing a function (super ugly, I know) that correlates the numeric value to the desired string value, but it's not returning the information correctly. I can select the same option, and every time it will log a different string value and a different numeric value.

My intention is to push "Poverty Alleviation" or "Education" or whatever the user selects to state (through the displayValue property on state), but it never returns the correct string.

Here is my code. Any suggestions are appreciated. Please let me know if any other code is missing that you need to see?

```
    class Sandbox extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            finished: false,
            stepIndex: 0,
            value: 1,
            ddvalue: 0,
            displayValue: ""
        };

    } 

    handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
        console.log(value)

if(value === 0){
    var test0 = "Event Staffing";
    this.setState({displayValue: test0});

} else if (value === 1){
    var test1 = "Environmental";
    this.setState({displayValue: test1});

} else if (value === 2){
    var test2 = "Parks and Recreation";
    this.setState({displayValue: test2});

} else if (value === 3){
    var test3 = "Arts and Crafts";
    this.setState({displayValue: test3});

} else if (value === 4){
    var test4 = "Infrastructure";
    this.setState({displayValue: test4});

} else if (value === 5){
    var test5 = "Household Tasks";
    this.setState({displayValue: test5});

} else if (value === 6){
    var test6 = "Education";
    this.setState({displayValue: test6});

} else if (value === 7){
    var test7 = "Animals";
    this.setState({displayValue: test7});

} else if (value === 8) {
    var test8 = "Disaster Relief";
    this.setState({displayValue: test8});

} else if (value === 9){
    var test9 = "Poverty Alleviation";
    this.setState({displayValue: test9});

}


console.log(this.state.displayValue)
    }

    case 3:
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
                <TextField hintText="Image URL" />
                <br />
                <TextField hintText="Any Additional Perks?" />
                <br />
                <DropDownMenu
                    value={this.state.ddvalue}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    style={styles.customWidth}
                    autoWidth={false}
                    >
                    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Event Staffing" />
                    <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Environmental" />
                    <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Parks and Recreation" />
                    <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Arts and Crafts" />
                    <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Infrastructure" />
                    <MenuItem value={6} primaryText="Household Tasks" />
                    <MenuItem value={7} primaryText="Education" />
                    <MenuItem value={8} primaryText="Animals" />
                    <MenuItem value={9} primaryText="Disaster Relief" />
                    <MenuItem value={10} primaryText="Poverty Alleviation" />
                    </DropDownMenu>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "value" field has no requirement on type.  If you want to put a string in as the value, you can easily do so;

```
<MenuItem value="Event Staffing" primaryText="Event Staffing" />
```

Also note that the `setState` function is asynchronous.  A `console.log` of the state after the `setState` is not guaranteed to show the changed value.

Comment: Thank you so much - I took your suggestion and now I've got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';

const styles = {
    customWidth: {
        width: 200,
    },
};

class Sandbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            finished: false,
            stepIndex: 0,
            value: 1,
            ddvalue: 0,
            displayValue: ""
        };

    }

    handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.setState({displayValue: value});
        console.log(this.state.displayValue);
    };

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <TextField hintText="Image URL" />
                    <br />
                    <TextField hintText="Any Additional Perks?" />
                    <br />
                    <DropDownMenu
                        value={this.state.displayValue}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        style={styles.customWidth}
                        autoWidth={false}
                    >
                        <MenuItem value="Event Staffing" primaryText="Event Staffing" />
                        <MenuItem value="Environmental" primaryText="Environmental" />
                        <MenuItem value="Parks and Recreation" primaryText="Parks and Recreation" />
                        <MenuItem value="Arts and Crafts" primaryText="Arts and Crafts" />
                        <MenuItem value="Infrastructure" primaryText="Infrastructure" />
                        <MenuItem value="Household Tasks" primaryText="Household Tasks" />
                        <MenuItem value="Education" primaryText="Education" />
                        <MenuItem value="Animals" primaryText="Animals" />
                        <MenuItem value="Disaster Relief" primaryText="Disaster Relief" />
                        <MenuItem value="Poverty Alleviation" primaryText="Poverty Alleviation" />
                    </DropDownMenu>
                </div>
            </div>)}
    }

export default Sandbox;
```

Here is the modification made in your code
    this will help to eliminate the if/else condition which you have written in the code